# Appium IOS gets All Devices ID's that are connected to MAC

Tags: java, appium

How do i call in my framework (In java) to “instruments -s devices” to Get all 
Device UDID that connect to the MAC and parse the result (UDID) to Array list ?

Answer (score 0):

Logic

```
1. Try running the command
2. Store the results in a variable or push the results to an array or hash
3. Print or loop the array
4. Use the results stored in the array
```